# Webscraping with Python: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='towardsdatascience.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to do web scraping using Request library. But I am getting gaierror and ConnectionError. I am not directly connected to the internet but through my company's VPN. I used below code:

```
import requests
get_url = requests.get ('my_webpage.com')
```

After some research, I got to know that I need to provide authentication using below code:

```
from requests_ntlm2 import HttpNtlmAuth    
url = "my_webpage.com"
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password')
page = session.get(url)
```

But I am still getting the same error. It probably is happening because of Company's own VPN. But I am not able to get the exact solution. Please help me out with this.